# Group of order 2016

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

I've come across the following exercise: Let $G$ be a group of order 2016 in which every element of order 7 is conjugate. Prove that $G$ has a subgroup of index 2. Does anyone have any idea of how one much approach doing this using Sylow theory?

Comment: You might try to show that $G$ has an action on some set of elements or subgroups. If that action were to have odd permutations, the elements of $G$ which act 'evenly' could be a subgroup of index $2$.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an outline of a proof. There may be easier proofs. I will leave you to fill in the details.

Let $P \in {\rm Syl}_7(G)$, so $|P|=7$. Any element of $G$ that conjugates a nontriival element of $P$ to another such lies in $N_G(P)$, So, since all elements of order are conjugate, we have $|N_G(P)|$ is divisible by $6$.

Sylow theory now gives that $|{\rm Syl}_p(G)| = 1$ or $8$, and we will deal with these cases separately.

If $|{\rm Syl}_p(G)| = 1$, then $P \lhd G$, and so there is a homorphism $\tau:G \to {\rm Aut}(P)$ induced by conjugation, with ${\rm Im}(\tau) = {\rm Aut}(P) \cong C_6$. The inverse image of the subgroup $C_3$ of ${\rm Aut}(P)$ is a subgroup of $G$ of index $2$.

If $|{\rm Syl}_p(G)| = 8$, then consider the conjugation action $\tau:G \to S_8$ of $G$ on ${\rm Syl}_p(G)$. The image of an element of $N_G(P)$ of order $2$ is a product of $3$ transpositions, and hence is an odd permutation. So $\tau^{-1}(A_7)$ is a subgroup of index $2$ in $G$.

Comment: There could be also be $36$ subgroups of order $7$ I think.

Comment: @MarkBennet No, with $36$ subgroups, the normaliser of each $7$-element subgroup would have order $56$, not a multiple of $42$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown If you are using Sylow (as referenced in the question), the possibility is open and has to be specifically excluded, and I thought this should be specifically mentioned, if only in passing, not least because the examples we first meet have only one or two possibilities for the number of Sylow subgroups of key orders.

Comment: @MarkBennet If $n$ denotes the number of $7$-subgroups, then there are $6n$ elements of order $7$. As these are all conjugate, they lie in a single orbit when $G$ acts on itself by conjugation. So the centralizer of one of them must have index $6n$, hence $6n$ must divide $2016$. That rules out $n=36$.

Comment: @Bungo I refer to my previous comment - I think the possibility needs to be explicitly ruled out, even if it is trivial, because it is a Sylow possibility, and Sylow is mentioned in the question - $36$ is ruled out by the specific additional structural information. I like this answer, by the way, which should have more votes than it does.

Comment: @MarkBennet You are right that this possibility needs to be ruled out, but as I said at the top of my answer, it was intended to be an outline solution, so that the OP could fill in the details. This is after all an exercise that he/she is supposed to be solving. You also need to rule out $288$ Sylow $7$-subgroups, which would correspond to $|N_G(P)|=7$. But I am glad you like the answer!!

Comment: @DerekHolt I'm fine with your answer, I just didn't want OP to miss the possibility.